# Does Kafka change binary data?

Tags: apache-kafka, binaryfiles, avro

I have some serialized AVRO data (mix of printable and not printable character) in the file data.bin and I send it by Kafka console client to the topic called topicname. When I read it by the console client (or my java code) from the topic, the data are corrupted. Text is ok but not printable characters are not.

**PRODUCER:**

```
user@server$ cat data.bin                            --------------- binary data, serialized AVRO (mix of printable and not printable characters)
▒▒▒▒▒▒XBADVANCED....

user@server$ hexdump data.bin
0000000 0000 0100 00ff 0000 0202 0200 a286 a882
0000010 58f7 0000 0000 0000 0002 0202 4142 5644
.......

user@server$ ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list server:port --topic topicname < data.bin
JAVA HOME:
user@server$
```

Then I try to read it by the console consumer from the topic:

**CONSUMER:**

```
user@server$ ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server server:port --topic topicname
JAVA HOME:
������XBADVANCED.....                                      -----------  see the not prinable data at the beginning, they are different the the original, the printable characters are ok
^CProcessed a total of 1 messages


user@server$ ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server server:port --topic topicname > outputdata.bin
^CProcessed a total of 1 messages
dev@pardbd3:bin$ hexdump outputdata.bin
0000000 414a 4156 4820 4d4f 3a45 0a20 0000 0100             ----------- it starts with "JAVA HOME:" string, real begin of the data is 0000 0100 bfef 00bd 0000 0202 0200 bfef efbd bdbf ....  
0000010 bfef 00bd 0000 0202 0200 bfef efbd bdbf
.....
```

As you can see text part of the data is ok but not printable characters are transformed to another not printable characters. What is the problem, is there any Kafka configuration which may cause this issue?

Comment: I don't think it is a good test because internally it is using `https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/ConsoleConsumer.scala` with a message formatter so you can have issues with character encoding. I would go for the byte array serializer/deserializer

Comment: @Paizo Wrong repo - it's in Apache Github org

Answer (score 3):

I doubt anything is corrupted. Console consumer only prints utf-8 content, depending on your terminal encoding settings, actually. Might be your source file isn't UTF-8. But Avro is not human readable, as shown by first cat output.

Console producer also expects newline delimited values, so if there are newlines being picked up in that binary file, then records might be corrupted.

If you plan on using Avro, Confluent packages `kafka-avro-console-*` scripts that use the Confluent Schema Registry. The producer scripts require a schema, and you type JSON, which gets converted to Avro matching the supplied schema. The consumer will print out the messages in human-readable JSON by deserializing the Avro using the schema from the Registry

Otherwise, if you are using the plain CLI utilities, you should probably be using avro-tools JAR file and run `tojson` into the topic rather than the raw Avro. Then you'd be producing and consuming JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Just running into same issue, found alternative:
kafkacat does exactly what you need for free :)

```
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t whatever_topic -T -P your_binary.raw
```

Detail information can be found here:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html